# pm2 json config not running app properly

Tags: node.js, pm2

Trying to get a nodejs app up and running with pm2.

We use SASS and rebuild the to css files on file change with "node-sass-middleware". It all works perfectly until pm2 starts auto restarting the app every time the sass middleware rebuilds a css file... which, is what we tell it to do with:

pm2 start app.js --watch
So, after some reading of the docs it seems you are meant to be able to configure pm2 with a json file and it has an option of "ignore_watch".

So, following the guide on github: https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/blob/master/ADVANCED_README.md#json-app-declaration we set a config json file up to look as follows:

```
{
    "name"        : "ourApp",
    "script"      : "server.js",
    "watch"       : true,
    "ignore_watch" : ["public/css"],
    "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development"
    }
}
```

The problem is, as soon as we try to run it the pm2 logs spit out 1000's of lines of log errors all looking a little like this:

```
PM2: 2015-05-09 15:32:00: Error: watch ENOSPC
PM2:     at errnoException (fs.js:1024:11)
PM2:     at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1056:11)
PM2:     at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1081:11)
PM2:     at createFsWatchInstance (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:24:15)
PM2:     at setFsWatchListener (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:47:19)
PM2:     at EventEmitter.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:177:15)
PM2:     at EventEmitter.NodeFsHandler._handleFile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:201:8)
PM2:     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:353:12)
PM2:     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
PM2: 2015-05-09 15:32:00: Error: watch ENOSPC
PM2:     at errnoException (fs.js:1024:11)
PM2:     at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1056:11)
PM2:     at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1081:11)
PM2:     at createFsWatchInstance (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:24:15)
PM2:     at setFsWatchListener (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:47:19)
PM2:     at EventEmitter.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:177:15)
PM2:     at EventEmitter.NodeFsHandler._handleFile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:201:8)
PM2:     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:353:12)
PM2:     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
PM2: 2015-05-09 15:32:00: Process with pid 9155 still not killed, retrying...
PM2: 2015-05-09 15:32:00: Process with pid 9155 still alive after 800ms
```

*thanks to the answer below*
This seems to be the culprit and apparently in linux world ENOSPC means no disk space left.. but with only 2.1gig being used on the entire dev server with a total HDD space of 25gig this cannot be the issue.

> PM2: 2015-05-09 15:32:00: Error: watch ENOSPC

Further more, when we run pm2 from cli as mentioned at the top is all works perfectly...

We really need this to work as it is causing havoc for the dev team.

Has anyone else hit this issue?

Thanks,
John

Comment: Completely stuck on this.

Answer (score 0):

[`ENOSPC` means no space left on the device.](http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html) So check to see if one of your file systems is full. Assuming your on Linux or another Unix-like operating system, `/tmp` and `/var` are likely candidates.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem though, I have 24gb available to the server and the total use ie:  `dh -h /` is only 2.1gb

Comment: `df -h /` only tells you the use on the root partition. If you have a separate partition for `/tmp` or `/var`, those could be filling up.

Comment: the size of tmp and var were not not that big at all.. 13mb and 745mb respectively... When i do not run pm2 from a json file there is no issue and all is fine..